# How do you export or save your wallet information for litecoin-qt on ubuntu linux?

Tags: litecoin, litecoin-qt

I just installed and finally synced up litecoin-qt on ubuntu linux. But how do i backup this wallet and password protect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File -> Backup wallet
```

Save your wallet file securely in at least two locations.

```
Settings -> Encrypt wallet
```

Ensure that you use a secure password, backup after you encrypt your wallet file if there are no coins in it to ensure its security.